# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.exception'

Tags: django, веб-программирование

Моя проблема заключается в том, что при попытке запустить лок.сервер Django в консоль выкидывает ошибку - **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.exception'**. Ниже будет приведён код:

```html
from django import forms
from .models import Tag
from django.core.exception import ValidationError

class TagForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    slug = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def clean_slug(self):
        new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()

        if new_slug == 'create':
            raise ValidationError('Slug cannot be created')

    def save(self):
        new_tag = Tag.objects.create(
            title = self.cleaned_data['title'], 
            slug = self.cleaned_data['slug']
        )
        return new_tag
```

С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль `django.core.exception` не найден, о чём собственно Вам и говорит ошибка.
В `Django` нет такого модуля.

Скорее всего, Вы ошиблись и имели в виду модуль `django.core.exceptions` (во множественном числе, на конце "s"):

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
```